# Модульный подход - Как можно задавать или изменять переменные внутри модуля?

Tags: javascript, frontend, модули

В модуле имеется переменная - хранящая кнопку выхода. В методе  `init` я пытаюсь ее инициализировать, чтобы работать с ней в других методах данного модуля, а в дальнейшем дать возможность обращаться к ней, вернув её как поле объекта. Однако значение `logoutBtn` остаётся `undefined` даже после вызова метода `init`.

Каким образом можно задавать/изменять переменные внутри модуля и в чем некорректность моего подхода?

```
var myModule = (function () {    
var logoutBtn;    

var init = function () {             
    logoutBtn = document.getElementById("logoutButton");                
};   

...

return {
    init: init,
    ...    
    logoutButton: logoutBtn,
    ...
};
})();
```

Comment: Скорее всего скрипт с модулем и вызов метода `init` происходит до того, как прогрузился весь DOM.

Comment: @СергейМишин нет, `console.log(document.getElementById("logoutButton"));` в методе `init` выводит элемент

Comment: переменную Вы изменили, попробуйте поменять прямую ссылку на метод, возвращающий эту переменную и вызовите его...

Comment: @StrangerintheQ действительно, работает, то есть возвращать переменную не получится? только геттер и обращаться `myModule.getLogoutButton()`?

Comment: @ZOOMSMASH получится, если менять поле у объекта, который Вы вернули через return

Comment: или более сложный вариант - через Object.defineProperty https://learn.javascript.ru/descriptors-getters-setters

Comment: @StrangerintheQ можно пожалуйста конкретнее про первый вариант, не совсем понимаю

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вероятно Вам хватит такой конструкции:

```
init: function(){
    this.logoutButton = ...;
}
```

но наверняка и внутри модуля надо будет обращаться к этому же полю, по этому, вероятно, надо сделать как то так:

```
var module = {
   init:...,
   logoutButton:...
}

return module;
```

Или уже так:

```
var myModule = (function () {    
  var logoutBtn;    

  var init = function () {             
    logoutBtn = document.getElementById("logoutButton");                
  }; 

  var module = {
    init: init
  };

  Object.defineProperty(module, "logoutButton", {
    get: function() {
      return logoutBtn;
    }
  });

  return module;
})();
```

Comment: Как тогда во втором примере  определять приватные поля и методы? Насколько я понимаю в вашем случае мы ко всему можем достучаться извне. И в первом примере меня пугает `this`, так как  если задавать функцию как, например, обработчик нажатия кнопки, то `this` начинает указывать на нее, что возвращает `undefined`.